# Listing X divs for print on A4 paper

Tags: html, css

I have a range of products in categories that i need printed on paper as a order sheet.

My idea was to get the following layout (landscaped):

```
Page 1:
+-----------+
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |
+-----------+

Page 2:
+-----------+
| 10| 13| 16|
| 11| 14| 17|
| 12| 15| 18|
+-----------+
```

The CSS I've tried so far does not work for me.

Current CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
        .noprint {
            display:none;
        }
    }

    .info {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 25px;
        font-size: 20px;
        border: 3px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .image {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .category {
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 20px;
    }

    .items {
        column-count: 3;
        column-gap: 20px;
        column-fill: auto;
        height: 80vh;
    }

    .page {
        page-break-after: always;
        clear: both;
    }

    .item {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .header {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .header > * {
        float: left;
        background-color: #E0E0E0;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .name_header {
        width: 70%;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 15px;
        float: left;
    }

    .pieces_header {
        width: 30%;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 15px;
        float: left;
    }

    .product {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari */
        page-break-inside: avoid;           /* Theoretically FF 20+ */
        break-inside: avoid-column;         /* IE 11 */
        display:table;
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }

    .name {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    .price {
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    .pieces {
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
    }

    .barcode {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

.page is inserted for every 25. product as a

Each .barcode div holds a products EAN13 as XML.

One product loop:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item header">
        <div class="name_header">Andet</div>
            <div class="pieces_header">Antal</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item product">
            <div class="name">13</div>
            <div class="price">kr. 29,95</div>
            <div class="pieces"></div>
            <div class="barcode">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What **is** the CSS you've tried, any what isn't working? Also, you'll need to post your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works on screen, and should work in print:

```css
body { margin: 0 }

@media screen {
   .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 100vh;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   .container div {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     height: 33.3vh;
     border: 1px solid red;
   }
}

@media print {
   .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 100vh;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   .container div {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     height: 33.3vh;
     border: 1px solid red;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

Note I have not used your code in order to keep the mechanics clear. See it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/bec6sryf/10/

Something to bear in mind, since you have a specific page size you'd like to target, in print you can always specify the dimensions in millimetres:

```
@media print {
   .container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 297mm;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   .container div {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     height: 99mm;
     width: 70mm;
     border: 1px solid red;
   }
}
```

Again, this is pseudo code - in reality, you'll want to account for headers and footers and margins, but this should provide a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much for a much cleaner solution. However, this causes the content to overflow the page to the right and not be included in the print.

Comment: As noted at the bottom of my answer, you'll need to adjust sizing to account for margins.